# Performance of JavaScript else if

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, comparison

Just wanted to understand if following two statements differ in performance and execution (I understand the best practice though)

```
if (condition) {
    do something;
} 
else if (another condition) {
    do something else;
}
```

and

```
if (condition) {
    do something;
} else {
    if (another condition) {
        do something else;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In my understanding there will be no difference in performance, just the readability.

Comment: They are exactly the same thing. I mean the **VERY VERY VERY SAME EXACT THING**.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir What if you `let`-declare something in the `else` block in the second sample? What would be the equivalent for that in the first sample? Is there even one?

Comment: @Xufox I was talking about the example he provided. If he add some instruction inside the `else` then it will be different. Then there will be no equivalent for that in the first sample.

Answer (score 0):

For explaining sake this:

```
if (condition) {
    do something;
}
else if (another condition) {
    do something else;
}
```

could be written like that:

```
if (condition) {
    do something;
}
else 
    if (another condition) {
        do something else;
    }
```

Since the `else` has only one statement (the `if` statement) in its body, the braces (`{` and `}`) are optional so the second code above is the same (with or without the braces) as:

```
if (condition) {
    do something;
}
else {
    if (another condition) {
        do something else;
    }
}
```

---

When a `for`, `while`, `if` or `else` has only one statement in its body the braces become optional. So this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    if(i == 5) {
        do something;
    }
```

is the same as:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if(i == 5) {
        do something;
    }
}
```

**THE SHOCKING TRUTH IS THAT THERE IS NO SUCH THING AS `else if`. IT'S JUST AN `if` STATEMENT INSIDE THE BODY OF AN `else` STATEMENT.**